# call totem on sound file in python?

Tags: python, totem

Im trying to use the python Popen function to play a sound file. However I cant find the file location for totem video player (default ubuntu video player). This is my code so far:

```
subprocess.Popen(['???','home/######/Desktop/python/programsIUse/alarm.wav'], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with the sound file 'test.mp3' in the same directory as the python script.

```
import subprocess

filename = 'test.mp3'
totem = subprocess.Popen (['totem', filename])
```

Comment: thanks! i will remember this in the future. for now though i have settled on using a program called mplayer